# Layman question about relativistic motion

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, acceleration, observers

I hope I can convey my question in a reasonable way:

I know that if Alice is moving towards Bob at $0.75\,c$ and Bob does the same towards Alice, then to calculate how each one of them measures their speed towards each other one would use the relativistic speed formula, and they will always see each other at closing speeds of less than $c$.

At the same time, I've been reading that when one accelerates, lets say at $1\,g$, one can accelerate for ever, and actually reach places that are millions of light years away, within their lifetime.

So my questions are:

1. what would a third observer in an inertial frame of reference would measure the closing speed of Alice and Bob?
2. What would Alice and Bob measure their closing speed to be?
3. How that gets reconciled with what I understand to be possible theoretical interstellar travel within one's lifetime when constantly accelerating?

Comment: You say "a third observer in an inertial frame of reference," but you don't specify what speed with respect to Alice or Bob this person is moving or in what direction.  So it could be anything

Answer (score 2):

### establish my measurements

Let's say that in my reference frame I am at rest, and in the middle.  I observe Alice moving toward me to the right at $\frac{3}{4} c$, and I observe Bob moving toward me to the left at $\frac{3}{4} c$.

I can't directly measure the "closing speed" of Alice and Bob.  I can only measure the speed of each relative to myself.  If I also measure their positions, I could calculate the time until they collided.  But due to time dilation the "time to collision" will not be the same for all observers.

### what does Alice measure?

The relativistic velocity addition rule comes from applying the Lorentz transformations for changes of coordinates to velocity vectors.  It tells us how to transform the velocity measured in one reference frame into another reference frame.  Starting from my observations we can transform each velocity into each other person's frame.

$$u' = \frac{u-v}{1-\frac{uv}{c^2}},$$

where $u$ is the velocity measured in my reference frame, $v$ is the relative velocity between my frame and another frame, and $u'$ is the velocity measured in the other frame.  Lets say right is the positive direction.

We can transform each of the three velocities I measured into Alice's frame.  From my measurements Alice's velocity is $u_A = +\frac{3}{4} c$, which is also the relative velocity of her frame compared to mine $v=+\frac{3}{4}c$

$$u'_A = \frac{u_A - v}{1-\frac{u_A v}{c^2}} = \frac{\frac{3}{4}c-\frac{3}{4}c}{1-\frac{3^2}{4^2}} = 0$$

So Alice measures herself to be at rest.  This makes sense.  Everyone is at rest in their own reference frame.

How does Alice observe my motion?  We need to use the speed I measured for myself in my own frame, $u_\mathrm{me}=0$.
$$u'_\mathrm{me} = \frac{u_\mathrm{me} - v}{1-\frac{u_\mathrm{me} v}{c^2}} = \frac{0 - \frac{3}{4}c}{1-0\cdot\frac{3}{4c}} = -\frac{3}{4}c$$
Alice measures me moving $\frac{3}{4}c$ to the left, toward her.
This again makes sense.

Finally, how does Alice observe Bob?  I measured Bob moving at $u_B = -\frac{3}{4}c$.
$$u'_B = \frac{u_B - v}{1-\frac{u_A v}{c^2}} = \frac{-\frac{3}{4}c-\frac{3}{4}c}{1-\left(-\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\right)} = -\frac{24}{25}c = -0.96c$$
Alice measures Bob moving $\frac{24}{25}c$ to the left, toward her.  This is correctly less than the speed of light.

### proper velocity

Velocity isn't the only thing that transforms between reference frames.  Position and time measurements do, too.  Each observer may measure a different distance traveled and time elapsed.

When I determined Alice's velocity, I used my meter stick (to measure $\Delta x$) and my clock (for $\Delta t$).  Her **coordinate velocity** in my reference frame is
$$v =\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}.$$
If I measure myself to be $3$ light-years from Alice, I would conclude it would take $4$ years for her to get to me.

A different way to define velocity is her **proper velocity**, which uses my meter stick, but her clock
$$v =\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta \tau},$$
where $\tau$ is her **proper time** measured with her own clock.
I observe Alice's clock to run slower than mine, so she will have aged less than $4$ years when she arrives to me.
$$\Delta\tau = \Delta t \sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}} = 4\,\mathrm{yr} \sqrt{1-\frac{3^2}{4^2}} = \sqrt{7}\,\mathrm{yr} \approx 2.6 \, \mathrm{yr}$$
She traveled $3$ light-years by **my meter stick** in $2.6$ years on **her clock**.  No one is actually moving faster than $c$.  It's just that this way of thinking about velocity is mixing different observers' measurements.

Because time dilation depends on relative speed, Alice could age an arbitrarily small amount while traveling any distance, assuming she can go fast enough.

It's important to remember that I measured her speed to be less than $c$. She also measured the relative speed between her and me to be less than $c$.  In her reference frame she is at rest, and I am moving $\frac{3}{4}c$ toward her.  Alice would observe that I arrive to her after $2.6$ years on her clock, so I must have travelled $$\frac{3}{4}c\cdot\sqrt{7}\, \mathrm{yr} \approx 1.98\,c\mathrm{yr},$$
so about $2$ light-years.  Her distance measurement is contracted compared to my measurement.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for adding two velocities $u$ and $v$ in the same direction is

$$V= \frac{u+v}{1+uv/c^2}$$

For velocities much less than $c$, the everyday formula $V\approx u+v$ holds true. You can try out for yourself any velocities less than $c$ and see that they always add to a speed $V<c$.

As for acceleration, you can apply constant acceleration and your speed (measured by an outside observer) will asymptotically approach $c$.  The reason you could potentially travel millions of light years in your lifetime is because of time dilation.  Your personal clock compared to the clocks of most of the galaxies in the universe will get slower and slower, at least until you started to slow down.

I'm editing my answer to give a **concrete example**:
For the case where you want 1 million years to be compressed into a human lifetime, the Lorentz factor $\gamma$ you want is approximately 15,000, which gives you a velocity with respect to light of about $v/c= 0.999999998$, or in other words $(1-2*10^{-9})$.

The Lorentz transformation equations relating your personal time $\Delta\tau$ and distance $\Delta\xi$ experienced to the time $\Delta t$ and distance $\Delta x$ that an outside observer sees you fulfill are:

$$\Delta\tau=\gamma(\Delta t-\frac{v}{c^2}\Delta x)$$

$$\Delta\xi=\gamma(\Delta x-v\Delta t)$$

Punching in the values $\Delta t = 10^6\, y$, $\Delta x = 10^6\, ly$ and $v = .999999998c$, we obtain $\gamma = 15,811$, $\Delta\tau = 32\, y$ and $\Delta\xi = 32\, ly$.

So you will experience a journey of about 32 years that covers a distance of 32 light years, and an outside observer will see you experience a journey of 1 million years that covers 1 million light years.  No one sees you move faster than light.

Comment: So if I can travel millions of light years in my own lifetime - didn't I by definition go past C? Thanks!

Comment: No.  From your perspective you will have traveled much less than millions of light years in, say, 70 years. From an outsiders perspective you will have traveled millions of light years and your journey will have taken millions of years. No observer will ever measure your speed as greater than c.

Comment: @Alen There is also length contraction at play. Basically, from your point of view, universe gets smaller as you accelerate. What it seems to you as a distance millions of light years in rest (with respect to galaxies) will look as few meters once you accelerate close enough to light speed.